# Recursively create folder in specific directories

Tags: windows, batch-file

During a recent backup/restore cycle I've realized that I managed to omit the 'tmp' directories from within the '.svn' directories, and because of this I can't update my working copies. The problem goes away if I manually create a new, empty 'tmp' directory so I am looking for a way to recursively go through each folder, find '.svn' ones and create a 'tmp' folder inside them.

As I don't want to mess up the existing folders I thought I's ask for help before I did something silly :)

Comments/suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!

PS: This is on a Windows machine so sadly Bash and other unix utilities are not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how many there are.

List the directories with

```
 dir/B/S .svn >dirs.bat
```

Edit dirs.bat in your editor of choice. Add `md` at the beginning of each line (since each line begins with something like C: you can use a fairly dumb editor - including notepad - to change C: to `md C:` ). Add /tmp to the end of each line (replace `.svn` with `.svn\tmp`). Save. Run the BAT file

Job done.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your suggestion. It works fine if the path of the folder does not contain any spaces, fails (and randomly starts creating folders in the same directory I run the batch file in, which is weird) if there are spaces present. I tried encasing the path in "s, that didn't help though. Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: put the directories in quotes when you do your text replace

Comment: Yes, turns out I was missing some quotes :/ Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The script above doesn't work on my on Windows 7 machine. The "`dir /b /s .svn`" doesn't get all dirs, I get a "*File Not Found*" error.

I changed the script to have /ad in addition to select directories only and that works! Here is the srcipt which works for me.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`dir /ad /b /s .svn`) do (
echo Fixing %%I...
mkdir "%%I\tmp"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to automate the entire process.  Put the following in a file like `fixtmp.cmd`:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`dir /b /s .svn`) do (
echo Fixing %%I...
mkdir "%%I\tmp"
)
```